# how to disclude development.conf from docker image creation of play framework application artifact

Tags: scala, playframework, build, sbt

Using scala playframework 2.5,

I build the app into a jar using sbt plugin `PlayScala`,

And then build and pushes a docker image out of it using sbt plugin `DockerPlugin`

Residing in the source code repository `conf/development.conf` (same where `application.conf` is).
The last line in `application.conf` says `include development` which means that in case `development.conf` exists, the entries inside of it will override some of the entries in `application.conf` in such way that provides all default values necessary for making the application runnable locally right out of the box after the source was cloned from source control with zero extra configuration. This technique allows every new developer to slip right in a working application without wasting time on configuration.

The only missing piece to make that architectural design complete is finding a way to exclude `development.conf` from the final runtime of the app - otherwise this overrides leak into production runtime and obviously the application fails to run.

That can be achieved in various different ways.

One way could be to some how inject logic into the build task (provided as part of the sbt pluging PlayScala I assume) to exclude the file from the jar artifact.
Other way could be injecting logic into the docker image creation process. this logic could manually delete `development.conf` from the existing jar prior to executing it (assuming that's possible)

If you ever implemented one of the ideas offered, 
or maybe some different architectural approach that gives the same "works out of the box" feature, please be kind enough to share :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually have the inverse logic:

I use the application.conf file (that Play uses by default) with all the things needed to run locally. I then have a production.conf file that starts by including the application.conf, and then overrides the necessary stuff.

for deploying to production (or staging) I specify the production/staging.conf file to be used

Comment: Here's the section in the Play docs that talks about how to an alternative configuration file as the main file: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using--Dconfig.resource

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it eventually.

`conf/application.conf` is production ready configuration, it contains placeholders for environment variables whom values will be injected in runtime by k8s given the service's `deployment.yaml` file.

right next to it, `conf/development.conf` - its first line is `include application.conf` and the rest of it are overrides which will make the application run out of the box right after `git clone` by a simple `sbt run`

What makes the above work, is the addition of the following to `build.sbt` :

`PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq(
  "config.resource" -> "development.conf"
)`

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the `mappings` config key of sbt-native-packager:

```
mappings in Universal ~= (_.filterNot(_._1.name == "development.conf"))
```

See [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#filter-remove-mappings).